# ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 32) vs (None, 1))

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to make a neural network with Keras and I keep on getting errors every time I try to preprocess data except with this code where I get the error in the first epoch

````
testData = datagen.flow_from_directory('test', class_mode='binary', batch_size=batchSize)
valData = datagen.flow_from_directory('validation', class_mode='binary', batch_size=batchSize)


model = keras.Sequential([
                  keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), input_shape=(600, 600, 3)),
                  keras.layers.Activation("relu"),
                  
                  keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3 ,3)),
                  keras.layers.Activation('relu'),
                  keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(4, 4)),
                  
                  keras.layers.Flatten(),
                  keras.layers.Dense(64),
                  
                  keras.layers.Dense(32),
                  keras.layers.Activation('sigmoid')]) #declare nn

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="binary_crossentropy") 
model.fit(trainDataset, batch_size=12, epochs=10)```


this is the error i get 

```  ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((None, 32) vs (None, 1))```
````

Comment: you have 32 classes, right? I think you did not set up your directory correctly ? check the document for flow_from_directory to see the issues.

Comment: Your NN has 32 outputs, while your trainDataset only has 1. If you want your NN to have one output, add a Dense(1) layer.